# Is Yuri as a genre ever referred to to using Katakana or is it only just kanji?

Tags: japanese-language

I know that the yuri genre is written with kanji and I was wondering, is katakana ever used to write or refer to the genre when used in a discussion. I myself have never seen it, but I wanted to know if anyone who knows japanese has?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Rarely. 百合 is more common. The other two seem to be A) part of people's names or B) Lily flowers.

A few searches on google, amazon or any eshop will give you a rough idea.

Just a language note, any word in Hiragana *can* be written in Katakana. Katakana can be used for emphasis or italics purposes (often loan words but not necessarily).

Comment: Note that Google does not differentiate the context. So you can have those searching for the flower vs a person's name amongst other things... So it might not be about the genre itself. There may also be significant overlap

Comment: FWIW, googling ユリ mostly returns ユリ目 and ユリ科, which is about family and order of Lily plants but not about "yuri" as a genre".

Comment: @кяαzєя True. A search with ゆり　and ガールズラブ(girl's love) seems to yield a 100:1 ratio so maybe yuri isn't the best term to use to find the genre.

Comment: @AkiTanaka Google does tailor your search results to your history so anecdotal evidence may not be so useful?

Comment: @nabulator true, but the main point is not about the order of the result, but the general result that it's not particularly about yuri genre... just like krazer said...

Comment: okay, after searching the webs for yuri literature, I think it's safe to say most people use the Kanji version simply because it is more specific than using katakana or hiragana, which are apparently just flowers and people's names

Comment: @nabulator is Katakana ever used to describe the genre? You said the kanji is more common, so does that katakana can be used or not

Comment: @ZainAlleck Of course it can be used, but only in a casual context where the subject (yuri the comic genre) is already understood.

Comment: @nabulator Have you seen it used? And what do you mean it can be as when I search with Katakana, I only get the flower, not the genre